# How to copy relative symbolic links

Tags: symbolic-link, copy

I want to copy `cp` in terminal a symbolic **relative** link into another directory, and I would like the copy to keep relatively pointing to the original target file.

How can I simply do it?

### Minimal Example:

Consider The file `fileAX` and the **relative** soft link `mylink`

```
somepath/folderA/folderX/fileAX
somepath/folderB/folderY/mylink -> ../../folderA/folderX/fileAX
```

Now I want to make a copy of `mylink` in `folderB` that keeps pointing to the original file `fileAX`. It should look like that:

```
somepath/folderB/mylinkcopy -> ../folderA/folderX/fileAX
```

How can be done?

Comment: They would be two different relative paths, so no. This either would have to be done manually (or scripted), or done with absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `cp` (nor the more powerful `rsync`) have an option to transform symlink targets. You'd have to do that translation yourself:

```
% realpath --relative-to=. "$(readlink --canonicalize-missing folderY/mylink)"
../folderA/folderX/fileAX
% ln -s "$(realpath --relative-to=. "$(readlink --canonicalize-missing "folderY/mylink")")" mylinkcopy 
% ls -lR                                                                                              
.:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 muru muru 4096 May 22 22:01 folderY
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   25 May 22 22:17 mylinkcopy -> ../folderA/folderX/fileAX

./folderY:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru 28 May 22 22:00 mylink -> ../../folderA/folderX/fileAX
```

Or, for this specific case, you can use `tar`'s `--transform` with, e.g., `s:[^/]*/::` to remove the first path component. I didn't expect it to transform the symlink target path as well, but it does:

```
% tar c -C folderY mylink | tar xv --transform 's:[^/]*/::'                                          
mylink
% ls -lR                                                   
.:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 muru muru 4096 May 22 22:01 folderY
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   25 May 22 22:00 mylink -> ../folderA/folderX/fileAX
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   25 May 22 22:17 mylinkcopy -> ../folderA/folderX/fileAX

./folderY:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru 28 May 22 22:00 mylink -> ../../folderA/folderX/fileAX
```